# Drag is working on whole window but i want it to work on just div by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to drag the div with id name id="dragme" How can I do it. And if it is possible the dragging div dragme should not have to go out side the div name limit.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $dragging = null;

    $(document.body).on("mousemove", function(e) {
        if ($dragging) {
            $dragging.offset({
                top: e.pageY,
                left: e.pageX
            });
        }
    });


    $(document.body).on("mousedown", document.getElementById("dragset"), function (e) {
        $dragging = $(e.target);
    });

    $(document.body).on("mouseup", function (e) {
        $dragging = null;
    });
});
</script>
<div id="limits" style="background:#ccc; width:600px; height:600px;">
<div style="background:red; width:200px; height:200px;" id="dragme"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also why do it let me point top left corner while dragging it should have to bring it from where i am point the mouse pointer and stay that point until leave.

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery UI [Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) plugin. It might be easier to use that instead.

Comment: It is not working on my page

Comment: You have to include the [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) plugin as well, which is separate from the main jQuery script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $dragging = null;

$("#dragme").on("mousemove", function(e) {
  if ($dragging) { 
    $dragging.offset({
      top: e.pageY - 100, //retract here
      left: e.pageX - 100 //retract here
    });
  }
});


$(document.body).on("mousedown", document.getElementById("dragset"), function(e) {
  $dragging = $(e.target);
});

$(document.body).on("mouseup", function(e) {
  $dragging = null;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="limits" style="background:#ccc; width:600px; height:600px;">
<div style="background:red; width:200px; height:200px;" id="dragme"></div>
```

If you want to use your code just retract half of the red box height and width from the offset like this:

Comment: Any script file to include not working even on a single page with all the snippet code.

Comment: How can you move with the name in id of js you use dragset and the id name in div is dragme ???

Comment: You need to include jquery as in the snippet. I have updated the code so only dragme can be dragged

Comment: Is your script in document ready function? Otherwise if you have your script before the htm it won't work

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to use jQuery UI draggable's [`containment`](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    containment: '#container'
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
#draggable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me around</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you double check whether jQuery, jQuery UI files are loaded, code is inside document.ready wrapper and the selectors are correct..? Or maybe you have an error in developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Solution using [jQuery Draggable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) + `containment` option for your code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/vqjuQ99YhxQYiiaXjZ32?p=preview

```
$(function(){
  $("#dragme").draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  });
});
```